# how to do aggregation in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have to fetch a record which have the name field that I give and a `subjectId` field of another collection for which I have the `subjectname` with me -- e.g., I would like to fetch a student record which have `name` lora and `subjectname` as physics (but the problem is I have `subjectname` with me but the collection student have the field id of that subject which is been already saved to some other collection say subjects --with _id ---subject _id act as foreign field in student record, I have student name and subject name with me, how can I access the student with corresponding fields?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options on how to do this in Mongo, with option number 1 being the one I personally recommend as it's going to be more efficient.

1. Split this into two queries:

```
let subject = await subjectCollection.findOne({name: subjectname});
// add validation that subject exists in case needed.
let doc = await firstCollection.findOne({name: name, subjectId: subject._id})
// you can use `find` instead if multiple documents can be matched.
```

2. Use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

```
firstCollection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            name: name
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "subject_collection",
            let: {subjectName: subjectName},
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: {
                            $eq: ["$$subjectName", "$name"]
                        }
                    }
                }  
            ],
            as: "subjects"
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "subjects.0": {$exists: true}
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: could you please also  comment the scope of variables, like subjectName field of this collection..etc